# Set minimum or maximum Height of Row of Grid in Xaml (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, gridview, xamarin.forms

I need to set minimum height of a `RowDefinition` of `Grid`in Xamarin.Forms using Xaml or code behind. I didn't find any property like MinHeight or MaxHeight. There is only Height property for `RowDefinition`.

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="10" Padding="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this to set your `MinimumHeight`:

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="10" Padding="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height= "Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MinimumHeightRequest="20">
        ...
    </ContentView>
</Grid>
```

Note: The `MinimumHeightRequest` will chose the minimum between your **requested height** and your **requested minimum** height. [Source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21485/the-minimumheightrequest-property-does-not-work-on-a-stacklayout)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem the same or similar way as Akash Amin.
In my custom control i added an empty boxview with a fixed height to set the minimum height of the row. The importent label was placed above the transparant boxview. So i did not place anything in the boxview.
I did the code in codebehind in my customcontrol.

```
var grid = new Grid();
grid.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
grid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto, });

var minSizer = new BoxView();
minSizer.HeightRequest = 30;
grid.Children.Add(minSizer, 0, 0);

 _label = new Label();
_label.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
_label.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
grid.Children.Add(_label, 0, 0);

...
```

(I think it is annoying that the MinimumWidthRequest and MinimumHeightRequest dont work as the most people expects them to do. In xamarin i mean.)