# Setting the Maximum Height that a RowDefinition can take Xamarin App

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to have the second row scale dynamically based on content but it should only grow up to a certain height. Similar to what chat apps are doing, the [expandable editor](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92439/automatic-expandable-editor) expands based on the text that it contains. My problem here is that if the text is really tall enough it may render the first row not visible.

**How do I set a maximum height for the second row so that the first row won't be obscured?**

ContentPage.cs

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:renderer="clr-namespace:Project.renderers"
             x:Class="Project.MainPage">
    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView VerticalOptions="Fill" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                     BackgroundColor="Green" 
                     HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                     Grid.Row="1">
            <renderer:ExpandableEditor VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                       MaxLength="3000" 
                                       AutoSize="TextChanges" 
                                       TextColor="Black"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

ExpandableEditor.cs

```cs
public class ExpandableEditor : Editor
{
    public ExpandableEditor()
    {
        TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    ~ExpandableEditor()
    {
        TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvalidateMeasure();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set MaximumHeight for a RowDefinition. You should set a maximum height for the VisualElement that placed in the row. You can do this with `MinimumHeightRequest` property.

Note: The MinimumHeightRequest will choose the minimum between your requested height and your requested minimum height. ([Source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21485/the-minimumheightrequest-property-does-not-work-on-a-stacklayout))

** Update **

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740250/set-minimum-or-maximum-height-of-row-of-grid-in-xaml-xamarin-forms) was asked in StackOverflow about 3 years ago.

Comment: `MinimumHeightRequest` from the property name itself, I don't think it's meant to aid your suggestion of setting the maximum height of the visual element.

Comment: That's right, but this is the mistake of the Xamarin.Forms team. You can get more information about MinimumHeightRequest on these pages. [1](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21485/the-minimumheightrequest-property-does-not-work-on-a-stacklayout) [2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66049/does-minimumheightrequest-work-at-all)

Comment: setting the `MinimumHeightRequest` still makes the ExpandableEditor to expand beyond the set size. I set the `MinimumHeightRequest` to 300... I actually saw those two links; however, I asked it here because it didn't help me.

Comment: I think 300 is very high for MinimumHeightRequest. Have you tried smaller values?

Comment: I've actually set it to 50 at first. Now, I've set it to 20 and entering lots of new lines causes the first row to be covered. Nothing changed :(